# Hyphen in parameter name for HTTP request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, google-api

I'm trying to send a HTTP GET request to a Google API that requires a parameter with the name "end-date" (with a hypen, not underscore). However, the following error gets thrown:

```
unexpected keyword_end, expecting '}'
        end-date: '2013-07-24'
```

Here's the code that I'm trying to use:

```
request = Typhoeus::Request.new(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v1/reports',
    method: :get,
    params: {
        end-date: '2013-07-24',
        start-date: '2013-07-01',
        access_token: access_token
    }
)
```

Any way to make params: accept the hyphenated names? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the "old" hash notation for those keys:

```
params: {
  :'end-date' => '2013-07-24',
  :'start-date' => '2013-07-01',
  access_token: access_token
}
```

Comment: Herp derp, yes indeed! Thanks!